# Blender Preferences Window Size

Tags: interface

Is there a way to remember and keep size of the Blender Preferences window?
It's too small and I have to adjust it each time I start Blender.

Comment: Do you want to open it everytime you use Blender?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to setup your own layout configuration.

I'd suggest:

1. Open Blender
2. Make necessary changes you want to the windows so that you'd get to the exact screen you want every time you open the Blender.
3. Press Ctrl + U {or go to top-left corner and click on File > Save Startup File > Save
   Startup File (confirmation)}
4. Now, close the Blender application window and try to re start the application. You'll see the applied changes to your interface.

Something like this: 
[image]

You can learn ways to setup the configuration reading the documentation here: 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/screens.html

There are tons of videos on customizing the layouts/ start-screen. One that I can recommend: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqPJJGzqrQk

Hope that helps!

Comment: I believe this question is about remembering the preferences window size specifically, and that can't be changed the way you describe.

Comment: Worse: If you have a big screen, it starts TINY, in the top left corner and it is not even properly scaled to show all content. This is very badly broken. So you end up resizing it EVERY TIME you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible. You can upvote this feature on https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/TBdbbc/